# Sum columns if text in another column matches

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google spreadsheet. This sheet has a column of numbers and a column of text.

I would like to have the sum of the numbers in column where the corresponding text in the text column matches a string.

I have attempted to do this with the following formula but it doesn't work.

```
=SUM(IF(REGEXMATCH(M1:M,"Target-String"), I1:I ,0))
```

How do I rewrite this formula to achieve my aim ?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: =sumif(M:M,"Target-String",I:I)

Comment: Thanks @user11222393. That works. I will mark it as correct, but I think you need to repeat it as an answer to this question for me to mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki since the solution was provided by [@user11222393](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11222393/user11222393) in the comments section.

```
=sumif(M:M,"Target-String",I:I)
```

[image]

#### Reference:

- [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?sjid=7246000245273739544-NA)

Answer (score 0):

Just a clarification (since not enough data is provided)

`SUMIF` will **ONLY** give correct results if `Target-String` is the **only** text in cell.

```
=SUMIF(M3:M8,"Target-String",I3:I8)
```

`REGEXMATCH` will produce results for **every occurrence** of `Target-String` in a cell whether it is combined with other text or not.

```
=SUM(INDEX(IF(
   REGEXMATCH(M3:M33,"Target-String"), I3:I33 ,0)))
```

*(**Do** adjust the formulae according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`SUMIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/)
- [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/)
- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`REGEXMATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/)